# compare Integers using .stream() in java

Tags: java, integer, compare, java-8, java-stream

I have an ArrayList and another int that come from the console.
I want to find the closest number larger than those int in the list using stream().
Why this doesn't work:

```
Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
int numOfRows = scn.nextInt();
int nextNumber = scn.nextInt();
for (int i = 0; i < numOfRows; i++) {
    String[] input = scn.nextLine().split(" ");
    ArrayList<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int j = 0; j < input.length; j++) {
        nums.add(Integer.parseInt(input[j]));
    }
    nextNumber = nums.stream().filter(x -> x > nextNumber).findFirst();
    System.out.println(nextNumber); 
}
```

Comment: You forgot to tell us the compiler error message (this code does not compile).

Comment: You will need to sort the filtered list or apply a minimum() operation to it. findFirst() is not the closest but the first number which is bigger than nextNumber.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your immediate problem is trivial to fix:

```
Optional<Integer> oi = nums.stream()
                           .filter(x -> x > nextNumber)
                           .findFirst();
System.out.println(oi.isPresent()? "Found: "+oi.get() : "Not found");
```

However, if you want to write code which optimally computes what you require it to, it is not the right approach. A far better option would be this:

```
OptionalInt oi = Stream.of(scn.nextLine().split(" "))
                       .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
                       .filter(i -> i > nextNumber)
                       .min();
System.out.println(oi.isPresent()? "Found: "+oi.getAsInt() : "Not found");
```

The advantage is that you never get an `ArrayList` involved and don't need to autobox the integers at any step, and you actually retrieve the *smallest* number satisfying the criterion, not the *first* one.

Comment: Then you can also save the array creation: `Pattern.compile(" ") .splitAsStream(scn.nextLine()).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt) …`

Comment: Yes, great point. And if OP actually needed `findFirst()` semantics, that would even be able to short-circuit regex evaluation.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find the smallest number larger than some bound:

```
private int smallestLargerThan(int x, List<Integer> list) {
    return list.stream().filter(n -> n > x).mapToInt(n -> n).min();
}
```

`.filter(n -> n > x)` drops all values less than or equal to `x`.

`.mapToInt(n -> n)` transforms the `Stream` to an `IntStream`, which is required for the next operation:

`.min()` returns the smallest element in the `IntStream`. Since the stream at this point only contains values greater than x, the returned element is the number you are looking for.

The code you posted won't compile because `.findFirst()` returns an `Optional<Integer>`, not an `Integer`. It is also semantically wrong because the first element is not necessarily the smallest as your `Stream` is unsorted.